# Searching a database with a ComboBox

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

for my college project I am designing a program that can read a Microsoft Access database about animals and display the data. I have managed to program it so that I can search by the animals name and it will display the records in a another form, but I need to be able to search other fields such as LatinName or AverageWeight and then display any results that have a match into a combo box  which the user can then select and the program would display the code e.g. if I were to type in 50kg and there are two records with 50kg, it would display them both and then allow me to select which one I wanted.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated, fell free to ask if you need more information.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnsear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsear.Click
    If (txtname.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Search")
    Else
        Try
            Dim newsql As String
            newsql = "select * from Animals where AnimalName like " & "'%" & txtname.Text & "%'"
            'MsgBox("select * from Animals where AnimalName like " & "'" & txtname.Text & "'")
            'msgbox(newsql)
            Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

            ' dim ds as NewDataTable
            Dim dt As New DataTable("Animals")
            ' uses the 2010 compatible connection string
            con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = h:\Animals.accdb"
            con.Open()

            da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(newsql, con)
            da.Fill(dt)

            Form2.Show()

            'show name in unbound text box
            Form2.nametxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
            Form2.latintxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
            Form2.locationtxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
            Form2.heighttxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(4)
            Form2.weighttxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(5)
            Form2.diettxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(6)
            Form2.statustxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(7)
            Form2.lifetxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(9)
            Form2.breedtxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(10)
            Form2.lengthtxt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(11)
            Form2.txtimage.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(12)
            Form2.socialchk.Checked = dt.Rows(0).Item(8)

            If dt.Rows(0).Item(8) = True Then
                Form2.socialchk.Checked = True
            Else
                Form2.socialchk.Checked = False
            End If

        Catch
            MsgBox("Item Not Found")
            'con.close()
        End Try

    End If

    If (txtopt.Text = "'") Then
        Try
            Dim newsql As String
            newsql = "select * from Animals where AnimalName like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            newsql = "select * from Animals where LatinName like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            newsql = "select * from Animals where Location like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            newsql = "select * from Animals where AverageHeight like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            newsql = "select * from Animals where AverageWeight like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            newsql = "select * from Animals where DietaryNeeds like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            newsql = "select * from Animals where ConservationStatus like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            newsql = "select * from Animals where AverageLifeSpan like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            newsql = "select * from Animals where BreedingSeason like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"
            newsql = "select * from Animals where AverageLength like " & "'%" & txtopt.Text & "%'"

        Catch
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: where you are displaying the records.? in Data grid view ?

Comment: No I'm placing them into text boxes on another form because I feel this would be the best way to present the data to the user.

Answer (score 0):

So you start the form with blank textboxes. You want to be able to search any of the textboxes by typing something in them. You should use multiple handles to get input from the textboxes, something like:

```
 Private Sub searchByKeydown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles nameTxt.KeyDown, latintxt.KeyDown, locationtxt.KeyDown, heighttxt.KeyDown ' and all the rest of your textbox names
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Return Then ' This checks if the return key was pressed and will start the search
        Dim tmpText As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox) ' grab the textbox that triggered the event
        If tmpText.text = String.Empty Then ' enter was pressed without a search term
            MsgBox("Please enter a search term")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim strSearchQuery As String = tmpText.text ' This is what the user wants to search
        Select Case tmpText.name
           Case "nameTxt"
                ' put in your search routine here for this textbox
           Case "latintxt"
                ' put in your search routine here for this textbox
           Case "locationtxt"
                ' put in your search routine here for this textbox
           Case "heighttxt"
                ' put in your search routine here for this textbox
         End Select
    End If
  End Sub
```

You will have more case statements, but this should get you going. Since you can already search by name, it's just a matter of changing the SQL statement for the other searches.

Answer (score 0):

Per NiteTrip's answer, I believe you would also need to set the KeyPreview property of the form to TRUE so that it will pick up the keypress.